Engine failure after takeoff during IMC. What to do?
Flying a Cessna 172 with IFR you have engine failure after takeoff at 500ft AGL during IMC, visibility 0/0.
What's the procedure?

There is no time for a "procedure". You save yourself however you can. 500 ft is high enough for a turn around to the airport and I would simply start a 30 deg banked turn to a reverse heading (into the crosswind if there is one) plus a little extra to get you back over the runway, and land on whatever presented itself when the surface came into view.
I would do the quickie checks like carb heat, mixture, mags, mayday, etc once established in the turn. You drill that stuff to death so your hands just fly around automatically doing those things while you concentrate on flying with your other hand. Leave the flaps up until you've completed the turn and can see the surface, and side slip aggressively if you need to lose altitude.
Too low to turn around? The old saw applies; fly it all the way until it's not flying any more. Contact with ground features while under control are much more survivable than while in a spin.

I disagree that 500ft is enough for a 180 back to the airport in a C172, that's heavily dependent on weight, conditions and terrain.

@GdD 500 feet is plenty even at gross in a 172.  He said IMC and specified 500 ft.  The alternative is terrain or a building you see at the last minute.  Bloody right I'd go for the turn back from that altitude. In a normal circuit/pattern you make a turn to final at 500 ft, A 90 degree turn. You think you roll out of a turn to final initiated at 500 ft AGL too low to turn another 90 degrees?

Visual conditions are one thing, but attempting a turn at the edge of the performance envelope in zero visibility is something I'd only do if the other alternatives were worse. If there's farmers fields ahead there's no point in risking a stall-spin fatality.

YOU DO WHAT YOU BRIEFED!
This is a great example of why it is important to brief each takeoff.  Have you become familiar with the airport environment.  Where is a safe place to land if an engine fails.  Thorough preflight planning will allow you to determine the best possible outcome for the takeoff today.
It may be possible to turn 180° at 500 FT AGL, but it is quite dependent on atmospheric conditions and weight.  To land on the opposite runway you will need to turn more than 180° to align up with the opposite runway.
At my home airport, there is quite a bit of flat land at the end of the runway that will allow me to land relatively safely if an engine failure does occur.
Every takeoff is different and a proper briefing will allow you the best survival outcome in a situation like you described.
